# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'openpgp'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm learning javascript, and I tried to import some modules using `npm` in my js file. To import some module using `require()` it works fine, but I don't know why, for **openpgp.js** I got a

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'openpgp'.

Here my **package.json** :

```
{
  "name": "User",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "openpgp": "^2.5.1",
    "truffle-artifactor": "^2.1.2"
 },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Here the setup of my app : [app config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoUod.png)

1. I run `npm install openpgp` inside my js file.
2. In my js I import modules by typing `var openpgp = require('openpgp');`,
3. Then I refreshed my browser and see my error : [browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUlgh.png)

For information, when I using the node console, modules works fine!

I'm really new in javascript, so may be I do something wrong. If someone have an idea it's would be helpful !

Comment: Have you already tried to run `npm install --save openpgp`?

Comment: Please post actual code, not images.  The important parts are probably package.json, whatever file is calling require for openpgp and if you have an npm-debug.log.

Comment: @Danibix yes I tried, and also using `-g`, nothing change ...

Comment: Are you using `require` in a client script? (Script running in the browser)

Comment: Yes @Danibix, cause I had import another module which works correctly :
`var Web3 = require('web3');
var openpgp = require('openpgp');`

or you talk about the module named `requirejs` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to require Node modules in browser script as in Node you need an external library. For example, you can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) lib.

Browserify let you bundle your scripts with needed dependencies into a single file that can be included in your web page.

---

Browserfiy website and docs should be enough clear. I report here main steps:

1. Install browserify on your system:

   ```
   npm install -g browserify
   ```
2. Bundle scripts with the `require("openpgp")` with the following command:

   ```
   browserify yourScriptName.js -o bundleFile.js
   ```

   (*where* `-o` *parameter is for choosing the output file, if omitted browserify will print output on stdout*)
3. Now you can include the previous output in your with web page with the following tag:

   ```
   <script src="bundleFile.js"></script>
   ```